# X3DOM - Dynamically Change ImageTexture with an Inline X3D file?

Tags: x3d, x3dom

When loading in an external X3D file via the "inline" tag, I am unable to change the textures my X3D file uses with html.

I am able to edit the X3D file itself and change the textures just fine, but I need to be able to change html values for the textures so that I can hook it up to PHP/SQL later.

Does anyone know how to make it so you can change textures for an inline X3D file? so far I have no found a way, and only am able to change textures without using inline/external X3D models.

Answer (score 0):

I realized you can assign a namespace to the "inline" X3D file you are externally loading, and then take the "DEF" id of the mesh you want to texture by prefixing it with the inline namespace followed by TWO underscores.

Then you can use javascript to do the following: `document.getElementById('inlineNameSpace__DEFID').setAttribute('item', 'value');`

So, for now I am handling this with javascript and it's working swell!